Is it unsafe to run pg_dump on a cluster that has pg_basebackup currently running?
I have run pg_dump and pg_basebackup hundreds of times. However, maybe for the first time I ran them at the same time and it seems to have caused the server to crash! Specifically, pg_basebackup was in the middle of doing its thing when I then did a schema-only pull with pg_dump. pg_dump hung for a while and then the postgres service crashed/restarted. The error I identified in the logs was:
LOG:  server process (PID 4093366) was terminated by signal 7: Bus error
DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT ... [(a long query definitely from pg_dump)]
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes

From what I can tell, a Bus error is some sort of race condition on shared memory?
Obviously, my lesson is to not do this again. But my question is whether this is an expected risk or not? If it is, perhaps there should be safeguards to fail more gracefully for the next person who might try. Crashing a database isn't the best way of being told "you shouldn't do that" if it is something that could be prevented with a simple check.

What is the complete version of the db server, and of each of the binaries (if different than the server)?  Is this readily reproducible?

Server, pg_dump and pg_basebackup are all 13.14 (Ubuntu 13.14-1.pgdg22.04+1). I think I did it twice without knowing it because at first I did the pg_dump and it errored and then I tried it again a few minutes later. I didn't find out until after that it had crashed the main server. I am definitely not going to try again because this was a production server so I don't know how reproducible it is - at least on this specific setup.

Not sure if this is of any help, but I see now that pg_dump produced this error: pg_dump: error: query failed: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected along with the same query string as was reported in the pg logs mentioned above.

It might be a sign of data corruption or of bad RAM, but I am not certain.

Unfortunately bus errors are pretty vague.  It could be a programming error similar to a segfault.  It could be faulty hardware.  But in this case I would expect it to be something like one CPU has something like an OOM condition, but can't communicate that message to the other CPU, so all the other CPU knows is a bus error occurred.  Was the system under heavy memory strain at the time?

I might have figured out the issue? Turns out that the machine that was doing the pg_basebackup had some incorrect memory config settings allocating more than was physically available. No errors cropped up until the process completed so I didn't know at the time. I don't know how that could have possibly affected a pg_dump on a totally different machine, but its the only other anomaly to speak of, and since its memory related, it seems very conspicuous.
